# React Router 6.4+: Entire main component gets duplicated if page with injected 'loader' prop is first started

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm fairly new to SPA and I'm trying to build up a little basic demo to start honing my skills. I've watched a couple of crash courses and so far so good, Reactjs is a relatively straight forward library and I really like it. But sometimes things start to act up and me being a rookie in the SPA world I am being thrown off pretty regularly. This is a very basic app with 3 pages, a Home, a Gallery and a Contact form. All the routes behave as expected when visited except for Gallery. If the user starts a session, say, in Contact and navigates to Gallery is all good. But when the user starts a session directly on Gallery ('.../gallery') **everything inside the RouterProvider component gets rendered twice for some reason**.

I know this is not a React.StrictMode issue because this behaviour is still present even in production mode. I'm fairly positive I'm not duplicating any JSX code inside my project but I could be wrong. Also, I've spent a good chunk of time looking for a similar question here but everything leads to take StrictMode off the index.js, which I'm sure this is not the case as I tried that many times but nothing happened. I'm providing below the core files, a codesandbox for real time testing (which for some reason doesn't reproduce the issue) and a production build on Netlify (the issue is present there as well).

*[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8ADS.png)*

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*index.js*

```
import React, { StrictMode } from "react";
import { ReactDOM, createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import "./scss/index.scss";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

*App.js*

```
import {
  Route,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/layout/pages/Home";
import Gallery, {
  loader as galleryLoader,
} from "./components/layout/pages/Gallery";
import Contact from "./components/layout/pages/Contact";
import MainLayout from "./components/layout/MainLayout";
import Error from "./components/layout/pages/Error";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/gallery" element={<Gallery />} loader={galleryLoader} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

*MainLayout.js*

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "./footer/Footer";
import Header from "./header/Header";

function RouterLayout() {
  return (
    <main className="wrapper">
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </main>
  );
}

export default RouterLayout;
```

*Gallery.js*

```
import { useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import { getGallery } from "../../../api/Api";
import ImgList from "./gallery/ImgList";

function Gallery(p) {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  return (
    <section className="gallery">
      <div>
        <h1>Gallery</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in
          massa et nulla condimentum posuere.
        </p>
        <ImgList data={data.gallery} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Gallery;

export function loader() {
  return getGallery();
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "demo6",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "sass-dev": "sass --watch --update --style=expanded src/scss:src/css",
    "sass-prod": "sass --no-source-map --style=compressed src/scss:src/css",
    "json-server": "json-server --watch public/data.json"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.24.4",
    "json-server": "^0.17.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.2",
    "sass": "^1.58.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
}
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require("path");
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html" }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "public", to: "" },
        //to the dist root directory
      ],
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              [
                "@babel/preset-react",
                {
                  runtime: "automatic",
                },
              ],
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
};
```

Codesandbox test: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-1-4ipltp-4ipltp
Production build: https://test-1-d321e6.netlify.app/gallery

Could anyone more experienced take a look at those? I'm really losing my mind trying to figure out what's happening! Any input and suggestion are more than welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to remove the script element that embedds `bundle.js` from the HTML template.

**Explanation**: HTML template has already a script element that embedds `bundle.js`, while `HtmlWebpackPlugin` injects a similar script element (see inject option [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options)) to the produced html (you can inspect this if you execute `npm run build` and take a look at the `dist/index.html` file). In the end, code is executed twice and `App` is rendered twice as well via `root.render(...)`

- Why is this happening only when loading gallery first?

[root.render](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot#root-render) first clears the `root` and then renders the app. By loading gallery first, it takes some time until `App` is rendered  (loading some data). The second `root.render(...)` is executed before the first render and clears the `root` (but it is empty anyway). Then both `App`s are rendered.

- Is this a ReactRouter loader issue?

I would say not, since if you try a different loader, an instant return for example like

```
export async function loader() {
    return { gallery: [] };
}
```

the "problem" disappears.

Comment: Thanks Evandelos for the input. That definitely did the trick, as you stated it was a duplicated calling to bundle.js. Removing that embedding line from the html makes the component render once. Thank you!